# The proper format of a 'sed' command?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Im trying to rename some files and need help with formatting a proper 'sed' command;

I have a file of movie episodes that looks like this;

```
SG1_s10e8"Memento Mori"
SG1_s10e9"Company of Thieves"
SG1_s10e10"The Quest"
SG1_s10e11"The Quest Part 2"
```

and I need to pad the episode # with a '0' like this;

```
SG1_s10e08"Memento Mori"
SG1_s10e09"Company of Thieves"
SG1_s10e10"The Quest"
SG1_s10e11"The Quest Part 2"
```

I'm sure sed is the correct tool, im just not real keen with the command syntax.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed 's/e\([0-9]"[^"]*"\)/e0\1/' file
```

Comment: Can you please explain what the `e` is doing in the expression above? ty

Comment: @jes516 have a close look at the input data and the desired output and think about why the `e` is important.

Answer (score 1):

you could try this:

```
sed 's/e\([0-9]\)"/e0\1"/'
```

Comment: Not bad but it'd fail for `SG1_s10e08"Memento More9"` for example.

Comment: No, because it only replaces the first occurrence; that would happen with the g at the end, as in 's///g', but not with 's//'. Right?

Comment: I had the wrong example at first, edited my comment now with the correct example. sorry. What I'm saying is if `e[0-9]"` does NOT occur in  the expected position before the start of the double quoted string but then does occur at the end of the string then the replacement would happen at that wrong location.

Comment: True. You'd have to add something more, like you did.